# What is the meaning of the expression 丘壑凛凛?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the expression 丘壑 there is a valley and 凛凛  means detached. I found the expression in a poem where it describes the feeling of the poet compared to an eagle, who sees the world from the sky, far and distant.

The whole sentence is 我的丘壑凛凛的心. My question is: does it mean my vast and distant heart, my heart is vast as a valley and distant as the eagle in the sky, a kind of buddhist detachment from the world of mortals?

Thanks

Rosa

Comment: see jukuu：丘壑 ３ examples： 胸中丘壑，intricate thoughts, 阿尔卑斯山的丘壑,folds of the Alps,缓坡丘壑,gentle hillock and valley,bkrs: 凛凛 (1) [cold]∶寒冷
水气凛凛
(2) [stern; awe-inspiring; severe; strict; be forbidding in appearance]∶严整而令人敬重、 害怕的样子
凛凛如生, additional jukuu examples:腊月天气,夜又长,朔风凛凛, 杀气凛凛,青凛凛的寒光中,
also note 威风凛凛

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 楊牧 《心之鷹》
>
> 鷹往日照多處飛去
>   沒入大島向我地投影
>   陽台上幾片落葉窸窣
>   像去年秋天刪去的詩
>   而鷹現在朝南盤旋
>   漸遠。我站起來
>   面對著海
>
> 於是我失去了它
>   想像是鼓翼亡走了
>   或許折返山林
>   如我此刻竟對真理等等感到厭倦
>   但願低飛在人少，近水的臨界
>   且頻頻俯見自己以鴥然之姿
>   起落於廓大的寂靜，我丘壑凜凜的心

「丘壑」的原義是「山峰與河谷」，因為它們常處於幽靜偏僻的地方，所以被引申為「隱居、孤獨、離世」的意思。

「凛」和「凛凛」都是「寒冷」的意思。

楊牧在《心之鷹》一詩中，用「鷹」來描寫自己的「心」。

「對真理等等感到厭倦」
是表達不滿、失望與心寒，所以楊牧用「凛凛」。

「但願低飛在人少，近水的臨界 …… 起落於廓大的寂靜」
是表達「孤獨、離世」的意思，所以他用「丘壑」。

「我丘壑凜凜的心」是指「我那離世而失望的心」。

---

The original meaning of 丘壑 is "peaks and valleys".
Because they are often in a quiet and remote place, 丘壑 is extended to "seclusion, loneliness, or solitude".

Both 凛 and 凛凛 mean "cold".

In the poem, 《心之鷹》, 楊牧 described his mood with "an eagle".

對真理等等感到厭倦 expressed dissatisfaction and disappointment, so 楊牧 used 凛凛.

但願低飛在人少，近水的臨界 …… 起落於廓大的寂靜 expressed loneliness and seclusion, therefore he used 丘壑.

我丘壑凜凜的心 means "my secluded and disappointed mind".

---

楊牧 was born on September 6, 1940 in Hualien County, Taiwan.

Comment: Talking of eagles and men reminds me of an old song: Zero she flies by Al Stewart: From the mountain he watches her, biding his time
But his eyes are the eyes of an eagle

Answer (score 0):

丘 is hill; 壑 is valley,

The term 丘壑(hill and valley) describes 'rugged landscape'

凛凛 is an adjective that means 'cold/stern'

凛凛丘壑的心 means 'A heart like a cold, stern and rugged landscape' (a poetic description of a majestic, stern and stoic heart)